# How to remove dialogue box from the exit popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I want to show a popup winodw before I closing my browser. Here is my code.I used following plugin

http://kbeezie.com/cross-browser-exit-pop/

here is the demonstration http://kbeezie.com/exitpop.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PopIt() { 
    $("a#trigger").trigger('click');
    window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt;
    return "Would you like to join our mailing list for other offers?"; 
}

function UnPopIt()  { /* nothing to return */ } 

$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;

    $("a#trigger").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'showCloseButton': false
    });

    $("a[id!=trigger]").click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt; });
});
```

but this code shows a  "Would you like to join our mailing list for other offers?" question before showing the popup window. I want to remove that popup question and only show that popup window there.

Comment: it is not possible, look at this question/ answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560532/what-can-i-put-in-beforeunload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** due to comments by OP.

You cannot use a custom onbeforeunload modal. It's a security measure that you cannot bypass.

**Original answer**:

<del>Simply change the line that says `return "Would you like to join our mailing list for other offers?";` to `return "Your message goes here within the string";`.</del>

Comment: please check the demonstration link.

Comment: I have. Isn't your question how to remove the message and optionally change it to something else?

Comment: nope. There is two popup windows, when you see that question ,simply click that "stay on this page" button, after that there will also show the real popup. I want that SECOND popup instead of the question. In the other hand, I want only show that second window while we closing the browser. Thanks

Comment: If my answer successfully disclosed your question, please tick the green check mark to help future visitors of the site :)